# Select distinct values from table

Tags: sql, select, tags, distinct

I have a table where I stored my blog articles,
The structure is like this :

```
id,title,description,tags..
```

In the tags column the data is stored like this : `tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4.`

I want to select all distinct tags from all my articles

```
ex:
article 1 :tags1,tags2,tags3,tags,4
article 2 : tags 1,tags4,tag5,tags 6

After query :
tags1,tag2,tags3,tags4,tags5,tags6
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Storing comma separated values is bad for this very reason. Store the tags in a separate table. You can either store them in a separate table having an `article_id` and a `tag`, or take it one step further and create a table `tags` with a `tag_id` and a `tag`. Then you can create a *junction table* to link `article_id`s to `tag_id`s. Your question is then easily answered: The unique tags are in the `tags` table.

Comment: I have a lot of articles and tags...and it's hard to change now..Exist a method to select the tags with current structure?

Comment: Change is easy. You can just write a single script to migrate the tags to a different table. Just as you change your code, you will have to change your database structure as well now and then. You don't have to do it in one go. You can keep the comma-separated tags until all your code is modified to use the new table. Trust me, it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

This ugly query will work for a maximum of 8 tags in one article but you can add more SELECT UNION if needed.

Since you didn't provide the table name I guessed "Article".

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT(Tags)
FROM
(SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Article.Tags, ',', 1)) AS Tags FROM Article UNION
 SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Article.Tags, ',', 2), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Article.Tags, ',', 1))+2)) FROM Article UNION
 SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Article.Tags, ',', 3), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Article.Tags, ',', 2))+2)) FROM Article UNION
 SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Article.Tags, ',', 4), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Article.Tags, ',', 3))+2)) FROM Article UNION
 SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Article.Tags, ',', 5), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Article.Tags, ',', 4))+2)) FROM Article UNION
 SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Article.Tags, ',', 6), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Article.Tags, ',', 5))+2)) FROM Article UNION
 SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Article.Tags, ',', 7), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Article.Tags, ',', 6))+2)) FROM Article UNION
 SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Article.Tags, ',', 8), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Article.Tags, ',', 7))+2)) FROM Article
 -- This query will work for a max number of 8 tags in one article : add more SELECT UNION if needed
 )
AS AllTags
```

As a side note, I totally agree with GolezTrol and you really should consider storing your tags in a separate table.

Answer (score -1):

You should have a tag table, and an association table in which you store assocations beetween tags and articles.

Comment: I have a lot of articles and tags...and it's hard to change now..Exist a method to select the tags with current structure?

Comment: There is no method that I know which would allow you to do that in SQL. You could write some code in whatever language you use on the server side to do that, but it would be slow, and require as much work as changing the structure of the DB.